# Jquery addclass on click anchor (Mobile Safari)

Tags: jquery, html, ios, class

I launched my new website today, and though it is fully responsive, I have an issue with a modal feature on my website. http://www.joepprevoo.nl/

Basically, this is what happens: When a user clicks a button, it adds a class to the modal-wrapper div that has the same id as the button that is clicked.

```
$('a.button').click(function(){ //Show modal on click button
    $('#portfolioModal'+this.id).addClass("in");
    $('body').addClass("modal-open");
});

$('.close-modal').click(function(){ //hide modal on click X
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.portfolio-modal').removeClass("in");
    $('body').removeClass("modal-open");
});

$('body').keydown(function(event) { //hide modal on 'esc'
      if (event.keyCode == '27') {
        $('.portfolio-modal').removeClass("in");
        $('body').removeClass("modal-open");
      }
});
```

Click on: `<a href="#portfolioModal1" class="button" id="1">View Project</a>`

Class 'in' gets added to `<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1">`
And the right modal window opens!

This doesn't work on Ipad's and Iphones though. I only have an iphone on ios 5 right now, but I've seen problems arise with this on ipads and other smartphones. When the button is tapped, nothing happens. I should add that on the'portfolio'page, it does seem to (partly) work http://joepprevoo.nl/portfolio.

I have already added cursor:hover to the css of the button (which is an anchor), but to no avail. 
(Got that tip from here http://www.shdon.com/blog/2013/06/07/why-your-click-events-don-t-work-on-mobile-safari)

I am at a loss here, can anyone tell me what the solution is?

Thanks in advance!

Victor.

**Edit:** This is weird, I created a simple jsfiddle and this works on my mobile safari (using a iphone with ios5). But pretty much the same code doesn't seem to work on my website.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Mx9K/19/

Comment: Not going to list this as an answer, as I cannot test it, and could be wrong. It looks like click and touch events are distinct, so I'd suggest making 'touchstart' event handlers that run the same code as the click handlers.

Comment: Hi @Ixonal, thanks for your comment. I replaced $('a.button').click(function() with $('a.button').on('touchstart', function() and unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: might be blind here, but your close-modal click event should be getting an error when it tries to call preventDefault, since that parameter isn't specified. Unless it's different in your code and you haven't updated it here, that is.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but I use `<a href="#" class="close-modal"></a>`that has a background image, and a bunch of other css styling. it's the X-icon in the top right if you click on a 'view project' button on the homepage. I don't seem to get any errors in my chrome developer console.

Comment: I mean when you define your .close-modal click event handler in code above. your handler function uses a variable named event, but it's not defined. chrome may just be silently swallowing the error. Then again, it may be different in your working code.

Comment: @Ixonal Even if i remove the 'event.preventDefault();' completely. The code still doesn't seem to work on mobile safari.